# Getting means of a several columns after grouping them

Tags: r, dplyr

Using the below code, I am trying to group my data (Diss) by "gender and CG_less14" and then obtain the means of columns 5 to 29. Then I would like to round the means to the nearest decimals. 
I would like to print the means in the console so I can manually use them for further analyses.

I got an error: Error in t(., round(colMeans(Diss[, 5:29]), 2)) : 
  unused argument (round(colMeans(Diss[, 5:29]), 2))

```
 Diss %>%
   group_by(gender, CG_less14) %>%
         t(round(colMeans(Diss[,5:29]),2))
```

Answer (score 2):

With `dplyr`, we can use `summarise_at`

```
library(dplyr)
Diss %>%
    group_by(gender, CG_less14) %>%
    summarise_at(5:29, ~ round(mean(.), 2))
```

---

In `base R`, we can use `aggregate`

```
aggregate(.~ gender + CG_less14, Diss, function(x) round(mean(x), 2))
```

---

A reproducible example with `iris`

```
iris %>%
     group_by(Species) %>% 
     summarise_at(1:2, ~ round(mean(.), 2))
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#  Species    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width
#  <fct>             <dbl>       <dbl>
#1 setosa             5.01        3.43
#2 versicolor         5.94        2.77
#3 virginica          6.59        2.97
```

---

Note that after we do the `group_by`, the data can be accessed with `.data` or with `.`, if we use the original data object to subset, it will get disrupt the grouping process and instead get the whole column

If we want to use `colMeans`, an option is to `split` the data by the grouping variable with `group_split`, loop over the `list`, `select` the columns of interest and apply the `colMeans`

```
library(purrr)
iris %>%
   group_split(Species, keep = FALSE) %>%
   map_dfr(~ .x %>% 
                select(1:2) %>%
                colMeans %>% 
                round(2))
```

Comment: @NaderMehri isn't this similar to `round(colMeans(iris[1:2]), 2)`

Comment: Thanks akrun. I installed package purrr and used library (purrr) but still getting this error: Error in group_split(Diss, keep = FALSE) : 
  could not find function "group_split"

Comment: @NaderMehri `group_split` is from `dplyr` can i know your `dplyr` version.  I used ` purrr for `map`

Comment: @NaderMehri  can you please tell me the issue with `iris %>%
     group_by(Species) %>% 
     summarise_at(1:2, ~ round(mean(.), 2))`

Comment: My dplyr verion: ‘0.7.8’

Comment: @NaderMehri current CRAN dplyr version is 0.8.5

Comment: I would like to obtain the means of my column of interest in the rows in the console. Something like this: iris <- colMeans(Diss[,5:29])
t(round(colMeans(Diss[,5:29]),2)). But I do not know how to combine the colMeans with group by.

Comment: @NaderMehri you still haven't replied to `iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% summarise_at(1:2, ~ round(mean(.), 2))` because it gives the `mean` of each column selected grouped by 'Species'

Comment: @NaderMehri you could update the dplyr version to current and test

Comment: This code generates below error: ris %>% group_by(Species) %>% summarise_at(1:2, ~ round(mean(.), 2)).                                          
   Error in UseMethod("group_by_") : 
  no applicable method for 'group_by_' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')"

Comment: @NaderMehri i guess it is a case of version error.  Please upgrade your dplyr package

Comment: After updating, I still get this error:Error in group_split(., CG_less14, gender, keep = FALSE) : 
  could not find function "group_split"

Comment: @NaderMehri can you check `packageVersion('dplyr')`

Comment: It is strange but I update the dplyr package but the old version is still in use.

Comment: packageVersion("dplyr")
[1] ‘0.7.8’

Comment: @NaderMehri I would consider doing this on a fresh R session after. removing the old dplyr version and installing new dplyr version

Comment: Try `remove.packages('dplyr')` then restarrt the R do `install.packages('dplyr')` assuming that your `R`. version is current.  e.g. I am using `R 3.6.2`. if you have an `R` version say `3.4`, the `dplyr` version available in the repo would be 0.7.8.

Comment: mine is R version 3.5.2 (2018-12-20). Should I update it?

Comment: @NaderMehri  II would update it because some of newer versions of `dplyr` work onl with recent R 3.6 and above